# Apply function that return data.frame/tibble on vector/data.frame column and bind results

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have a function that fetches some data from a database. It takes a single parameter and returns a data.frame. I would like to use an input vector of these parameters and pipe them to map or similar function that takes each elment and returns the db results. The results can differ in rows but columns are always the same. How do I go about without looping and row-binding? (for i in ..)

I tried the following route:

```
myfuncSingleRow<-function(nbr){ 
data.frame(a=nbr,b=nbr^2,c=nbr^3)}

myfuncMultipleRow<-function(nbr){ 
    data.frame(a=rep(nbr,3),b=rep(nbr^2,3),c=rep(nbr^3,3))}

a<-data.frame(count=c(1,2,3))

myfuncSingleRow(2)
myfuncMultipleRow(2)


a %>% select(count) %>% map_dfr(.f=myfuncSingleRow) #output as expected    
a %>% select(count) %>% map_dfr(.f=myfuncMultipleRow) #output not as expected
```

Now this does not work as intended either. Example myFuncMultipleRow, I was expecting the first 3 rows to be equal, the next 3 equal, and the same for the final 3. Example using myFuncMultipleRow:

Getting

```
  a b  c
1 1 1  1
2 2 4  8
3 3 9 27
4 1 1  1
5 2 4  8
6 3 9 27
7 1 1  1
8 2 4  8
9 3 9 27
```

Wanting:

```
  a b  c
1 1 1  1
2 1 1  1
3 1 1  1
4 2 4  8
5 2 4  8
6 2 4  8
7 3 9 27
8 3 9 27
9 3 9 27
```

As usual, I am probably not using the functions correctly, but a bit stuck here a do not want to resolve to the old loop and rbind which would probably be a performance bottleneck. Any takers?

EDIT: As pointed out "each" argument in "rep" does solve this one, but does not solve the main issue. If map did iterate and call the function for each element, then using parameter "each" and "times" for function "rep" should yield the same result. The function passed to map is not vectorized, but assumes a single parameter of length 1. 
The solution need to do:

```
res<-data.frame()
for(i in a) res<-rbind(res,myfuncMultipleRow(i))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after looking at latest purrr 0.3.0 (was on older version) map_depth pointed to the right direction.

```
a %>% select(count)%>% map_depth(.depth=2,.f=myfuncMultipleRow) %>%  map_dfr(.f=bind_rows)
```

Dropping map_depth() , bind_rows() and nesting instead:

```
a %>% select(count)%>% map_dfr(~map_dfr(.,myfuncMultipleRow))
a %>% select(count)%>% map_dfr(.f=function(x) map_dfr(x,.f=myfuncMultipleRow))
```